# returning pointer to a structure in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, char, structure

this program **returns a pointer to a structure**.
When i print the contents, the **name** is not being displayed properly, where as the other two variables are being properly printed.
What could be the problem?
Here is the code in C

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct student
    {
        char name[20];
        int marks;
        int rank;
    };
struct student stu;
struct student *create();

void main()
{
    struct student *ptr;
    ptr = create();
    printf("%s\t %d\t %d\t",ptr->name,ptr->marks,ptr->rank);
}

struct student *create()
{
    struct student stu = {"john",98,9};
    struct student *ptrr;
    ptrr = &stu;
    return ptrr;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that you're returning a pointer to a *local* variable. Local variables goes out of scope once the function they are defined in returns. That means that the pointer you return will point to unallocated memory after the function returns. Using that pointer will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

There are three ways to solve this:

1. Use a global variable, and return a pointer to that. The lifetime of a global variable is the lifetime of the program.
2. Use a `static` local variable. It also will have the lifetime equal to the program.
3. Allocate the structure dynamically when needed, and return that pointer.

Points 1 and 2 have a problem in that then you can only have a single object. If you modify that object, all places where you have a pointer to that single object will see those changes.

Point 3 is the way I recommend you go. The problem with that is that once you're done with the object, you have to free the memory you allocate.

Comment: **Local variables goes out of scope**
i had the same question in my mind while i was asking
this question.But i could not understand why it was partially working and partially not working.
Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You create a local variable `stu` which lives in a function `create()`. A pointer on this variable is incorrect outside function `create()`.

Answer (score 1):

As [Joachim Pileborg answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24822817/841108) you should not return a pointer to a local variable. BTW if you compile with a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) using `gcc -Wall -g` (e.g. enabling almost all warnings and debug info) you should get a warning.

So in practice, you should *decide* that your `create` returns a heap pointer, and adopt then obey the *convention* that its caller is freeing that pointer.

```
 void main() {
   struct student *ptr;
   ptr = create();
   printf("%s\t %d\t %d\t",ptr->name,ptr->marks,ptr->rank);
   free (ptr);
 }

struct student *create() {
  struct student stu = {"john",98,9};
  struct student *ptrr = malloc(sizeof struct student);
  if (!ptrr) { perror("malloc student"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
  *ptrr = stu;
  return ptrr;
}
```

Read carefully the wikipages on [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation), [manual memory management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manual_memory_management), [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management/wiki/Manual_memory_management), [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) and [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) man page. If you have the luck of coding on Linux, learn about [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

PS. Always test the result of `malloc` (against failure). *Always* initialize the obtained memory zone (maybe clearing it with [memset(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memset.3.html)....).

#### addenda: good habits

You should compile with all warnings and debug info. If using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), compile with `gcc -Wall -g` and improve your code till you got no warnings.

You definitely should learn how to **use the debugger** (on Linux, `gdb`) and be able to step by step the program and display various local variables.

#### addenda: using Boehm GC

For completeness (notably on Linux), and only *once you become an expert C programmer*, you might consider using Boehm's conservative [garbage collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) (see [this link](http://hboehm.info/gc/)): then you would `GC_malloc` instead of `malloc` and you won't need to explicitly `free` the allocated pointer zone. The Boehm collector might (perhaps later, notably in bigger programs) "magically" free the memory for you. But learning about garbage collection and [reference counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting) (which can be viewed as a poor form of GC, since it does not manage well [circular references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference)) is useful. You could also design your own GC (difficult task), like I did in [qish](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/qishintro.html) or [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) ...

Comment: Yes.Creating memory for the structure dynamically is the way out.
thanks for the code.

Comment: Well, actually (as the OP proved), you *can* return a pointer to a local variable.  It just doesn't do much good to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You created stu locally on the stack in your create function. When you returned from that function, the stack was popped, invalidating the data you pointer points to.