# Receive SIGSEGV signal when using malloc for char * in Linux Qt Creator C++

Tags: c++, linux, char, malloc, segmentation-fault

When I run the following code to allocate memory for char * using malloc() on QT Linux C++, SIGSEGV is signaled after about 250 executions.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
   char * test = (char * )malloc(500);
   test = "mas";
   cout<<test<<endl; 
}
```

I tried to use free() or delete() but they also trigger system signal.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you're stepping on your malloc()'ed pointer.  Stepping on it multiple times:

```
// Original test case
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
   char * test = (char * )malloc(500);
   test = "mas";  // BAD!!! 
                  // You've just stepped on your "malloc'ed" pointer with a *different pointer!!!!
   cout<<test<<endl; 
}
```

Here is an alternative.  Note that you've also got to have some way to "remember" the pointer for each malloc(), so you can "free()" it at the appropriate time:

```
// Better:
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
   char * test = (char * )malloc(500);
   if (test == NULL) {
     cout <<  "malloc error!" << endl;
     break;
   }
   strcpy (test, "mas");
   cout<<test<<endl; 
   free (test);
}
```

Comment: Hi, the free() method results in SIGABRT signal. How can I avoid that?

Comment: Hi - I added a (necessary!) test for "mallocI)" error.  Q: What platform are you on?  Windows?  Linux?  Q: What compiler are you using?  MSVS?  GCC?  Q: Could you try running the code as-is, in a debugger?  ALSO: Please look at John Dibling's answer.  He's trying to tell you the same thing I am...

Comment: Hi, I am on Linux. I am using GCC with QT Creator. I tried the code and it is working now. no break occurred. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You've changed the value of the pointer test.  You need to use memcpy or the like to copy the value "mas" into the buffer.

Better yet, use std::string

Comment: Hi, I changed it, but malloc is still causing SIGSEGV signal.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
test = "mas";
```

Doesn't do what you think it does.  You *think* it copies the string `"mas`" in to the buffer pointed to by `test`.  What it *actually* does is it changes what `test` points to.  Instead of pointing to the memory you allocated with the `malloc`, now it points to a statically allocated char buffer.

Comment: Thank you! I changed the code to use strcpy() and it works perfect now.

Answer (score 1):

When you're allocating memory with malloc or new you get only a pointer in return, so you have to approach to that differently - with functions like strcpy, strcmp (if you need to check equality of texts you can't compare only pointers either). Read more about pointers in any C++ book. It's possible to create texts without allocating memory explicitly, for example, this is legal:

```
const char *text = "my text";
```

But further modifications like you showed in question are not (notice const here, it gives us more safety). In this case text is created somewhere in memory by compiler itself (i'm simplifying things now) and only pointer is assigned. In that case you cannot modify that text (at least not safe).

Next thing, when you are allocating any memory you have to free it manually, at least in languages like C/C++ where memory management (garbage collectors etc.) don't really exist. If you'll skip that step you'll run into trouble (out of memory exceptions for example) faster than you think.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. I tried to use delete() or free() after the cout<< sentence, but it incurs SIGBRT all the time. So I really don't know what is happening.

Comment: Look, I assume you still assigning pointers like in the question. Malloc returns you a pointer, it's stored in test, next you are assigning pointer to "mas" (stored somewhere in program) to same variable, when you are trying to free it, you encounter a problem, because you cannot modify and delete that kind of memory. Use functions like strcpy or even memcpy to do it. Update your question if you changed anything with it. I'll encourage you to fix it and don't try to go around the problem because understanding of it is essential in programming. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

this statement:

```
    test = "mas";
```

does not copy strings, but pointers.

To copy a string in C, use *carefully* [strcpy(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html) (often `strncpy`is better).

```
    strcpy(test, "mas");
```

But you really should use (as [Vinbot answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24832889/841108)) [std::string](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/string.html) since you code in C++

Also, compile C++ code on Linux with `g++ -g Wall` (and C code with `gcc -g -Wall`) to get warnings and debug info. Learn how to use the `gdb` debugger and also [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24822869/841108) to a related question.

Comment: OK, I will use string, it looks like there is a problem to use malloc

Comment: There is no problem in using malloc, but you got a temporary problem in understanding what pointers and strings are. This is normal, pointer is a tricky concept. So take time reading about it!

Comment: Thank you! I've changed everything in Char* to string. Every thing is running well now. malloc really causes SIGSEGV after running a while, about 250 times, for char *. I still don't know why.